# PHP PDO: Multiple objects extend dbwrapper; How many MySQL connections?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

**The Situation:**

- I am using a db class as a wrapper (dbwrapper) to open and close db connections via PHP PDO
- I have 3 separate classes which extend this db wrapper
- I instantiate 3 objects from said classes and in the course of their existence they each make db queries
- MySQL used in this case.

When the methods of the 3 classes require db access they each create PDO objects internally, making use of the dbwrapper which they extended.  Each object is storing its PDO object in a member/field for reference by itself.

**The Question:** My question is this... is each object creating a separate connection to the database, making 3 in total?  Is each client of Apache creating only one connection to the database or is each object using the db in a php application creating a connection. (sounds inefficient!)

**The Reason:** I would like to understand how these connections are handled.

I am trying to decide if it would be better to have each class extend the dbwrapper or if it would be better to initialize the dbwrapper without making an automatic connection the db, handle that when its needed.  Instead I would pass the dbwrapper to each objects constructor as they are initialized... letting them use that reference.  If multiple db connections are happening then I think this would be the best way to minimize overhead while overcoming issues of object's scope and access.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ charles, thanks that is a good idea. I gave it a try but I don't think I can sleep a PDO transaction. I think from the programmers standpoint the behavior is atomic. You give PDO a request and it does its thing behind the scenes then offers you the result set which you can iterate through.  Thanks for the advice on the dbwrapper / constructor issue.  That clears up that question for me.  I had a feeling that would be the way to go. I would point you up but I have no rep :)

Comment: Oh yeah, it's surely inefficient. One client starts a transaction and all of sudden another one comes along. And getting all the money transferred by first one. Marvelous!

Answer (score 1):

> is each object creating a separate connection to the database, making 3 in total?

Maybe.  I don't know, but *here's how to find out*.  While your script is running, connect to MySQL via your client of choice (like the command line) and issue the command `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`  You'll get a list of active connections.

You might need to insert a `sleep` in your script to keep it alive long enough for you to run the process list command when you've instantiated and are working on all three objects.

You'll see either one connection or three.  Then you'll have your answer.

(The answer will vary depending on the underlying driver.  Some drivers will reuse the connection if the DSN is identical.)

> Instead I would pass the dbwrapper to each objects constructor as they are initialized... letting them use that reference

This is the common practice.  Database handles are prime candidates for the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern as well.